Where to use tdlib options?
The TDlib documentation page mentions some options. Where and how can they be used? I just haven't found any mention of it anywhere.
I'm especially interested in where is the guidance on using options in the C interface. That said, I can find where to enter options in the TDlib wrapper - tdl (tdl.CreateClient and tdlibParameters in ClientOptions) and I assume that tdl wraps the C interface. But I can't find a way to pass the options in the C interface, and I want to know if there is really no way.

Such an option can be set or get using setOption and getOption.
